# Finite intensity of Lévy measure implies compound Poisson process

Tags: poisson-process, levy-processes

Suppose $X$ is a Lévy process with triplet $(b,\sigma^2,\nu)$ and finite intensity, so $\nu(\mathbb R)<\infty$.

Why does it follow immediately that the jump part of $X$ can be described by a compound Poisson process?